# Learn ruby the hard way Ex39: Adding key to Array

Tags: arrays, ruby

I'm very stuck at this exercise, so I would be grateful for a very detailed answer.

Question:

At what point is a key added to the aDict array? I can only see the created index of the key being added to the array.
(return aDict [bucket-id]?)

I'm looking at this code:

```
module Dict

  def Dict.new(num_buckets = 256)
    #Initializes Dict with the given number of buckets.

     aDict = []

     (0...num_buckets).each do |i|
      aDict.push([])
    end

    return aDict
  end

  def Dict.hash_key(aDict,key)
    #given a key this will create a number
    #turning it into an index for one of aDicts buckets

    return key.hash % aDict.length
  end

  def Dict.get_bucket(aDict, key)
    #Given a key, find the bucket where it would go.

    bucket_id = Dict.hash_key(aDict,key)
    return aDict[bucket_id]
  end

  def Dict.get_slot(aDict, key, default=nil)
    #Returns the index, key and 
    #value of a slot found in a bucket.

    bucket = Dict.get_bucket(aDict,key)

    bucket.each_with_index do |kv, i|
      k, v = kv
      if key == k
        return i, k, v
      end
    end

    return -1, key, default
  end

  def Dict.get(aDict, key, value)
    #Gets the value in a bucket for the given key or the default

    i, k, v = Dict.get_slot (aDict,key, Value, default = default)
      return v
  end

  def Dict.set(aDict,key,value)
    #Sets the key to the value,
    #replacing any existing value.

    bucket = Dict.get_bucket(aDict, key)

    i,k,v = Dict.get_slot(aDict, key)

      if [i] >= 0
        bucket[i] = [key,value]
      else
        bucket.push([key,value])
      end
   end
```

Let's say I import Dict.rb to another file and I want it to run:

```
require .\dict.rb

#create mapping of state to abbreviation

states Dict.new()
Dict.set( states, Oregon, OR)
```

When is the key (Oregon) in the bucket so that it can be returned by aDict[bucket_id]?

Comment: top part of your code got left out of the code block. also, could you indent your code? I want to help but it's a bit hard to read as-is. https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so first the structure of the hash table `aDict` will look like this with some keys in it:

```
[0] => [[k1, v1], [k2, v2]]

[1] => [[k3, v3]]

[2] => []
```

`0,1,2` are the indices. At each index position, you have another array and each element of *this* array is a two element array containing a key and value. For example, this means that `k3` is at `aDict[1][0][0]`

So, when you want to insert a key and value in the hash, the `Dict.set` method gets called

```
def Dict.set(aDict,key,value)
  #Sets the key to the value,
  #replacing any existing value.

  bucket = Dict.get_bucket(aDict, key)
```

`get_bucket` calculates the first index by taking the mod of the key hash with the size of the array. It then returns the array stored at that index. (For example: `bucket = aDict[1]`)

```
  i,k,v = Dict.get_slot(aDict, key)
```

`get_slot` finds out which index in `bucket` array has your key and returns the index number along with the key and value. If it does not exist, it returns -1 for no index, the key and the default value (`nil`)

(For example: `i, k, v` will be `0, k3, v3` because `[k3, v3]` is at `aDict[1][0]`. If you were looking for `k4`, `i, k, v` would have been `-1, k4, nil`)

```
    if i >= 0
      bucket[i] = [key,value]
    else
      bucket.push([key,value])
    end
 end
```

This bit is easy. If `i` is not -1, then you update the location with your key and value otherwise you push new two element array at the end of the array.

Comment: Great answer , clarified alot to me. There is still one hole in my understanding here though: At the beginning the array is empty, at what point does for example [k3,v3] enter aDict, I just don't get that.

Comment: You call `Dict.set(aDict, k3, v3)`, `bucket_id` will be 1 and `bucket = []`. `get_slot` will return `-1, k3, nil` because it cannot find `k3` and you'll just do `bucket.push [k3,v3]`